# How to check if a given string is a substring of an element of a list

Tags: string, list

According to documentation, `member` checks if a a given element is an element of a list. For example if the list, say `my_list` consists of **apple** and **orange**, `(member "apple" my_list)` returns true.

Is there an easy way to check if a given string is a part of a string of a list. For example **ap** is a part of a string  of the above list.
Hence it would be desirable to have a function like `my-function`  such that `(my-function "ap" my_list)` returns true.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use the [Common Lisp compatibility layer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/):

```
(require 'cl-seq)
(cl-member "ap" '("foo" "apa" "bar") :test #'string-match)
==> ("apa" "bar")
```

PS. This is not directly relevant to your question, but if you have a few minutes to kill, keep reading. ;-)

Note that Emacs maintainers have traditionally eschewed CL (starting with the original political animosity of RMS towards the CL creators).

See [Controversy of Common Lisp Package in Emacs Lisp](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_common_lisp_in_emacs.html) for attempts to justify the hostility in technical terms.

Answer (score 5):

The function that comes to my mind at least would be `cl-member` using a `string-match-p` test.

Here's a short example that shows how to use it:

```
ELISP> (setq testing '("an apple" "a pear" "a grape"))
("an apple" "a pear" "a grape")

ELISP> (cl-member "apple" testing)
nil
ELISP> (cl-member "an apple" testing)
nil
ELISP> (cl-member "an apple" testing :test #'string=)
("an apple" "a pear" "a grape")

ELISP> (cl-member "a pear" testing :test #'string=)
("a pear" "a grape")

ELISP> (cl-member "a pear" testing :test #'string-match-p)
("a pear" "a grape")

ELISP> (cl-member "pear" testing :test #'string-match-p)
("a pear" "a grape")

ELISP> (cl-member "xx" testing :test #'string-match-p)
nil
```

Note that `member` and `cl-member` doesn't actually return `true` but the
sublist that contains the sought element. That in turn will eventually evaluates
to `true` in tests, but That's mostly a minor detail.

**Edit:**

Sean pointed out an important detail about `string-match` and `string-match-p`:
Regular expression meta-characters in the search string might give an erroneous
result. If that's a problem you could examine the raw sequence instead with
`cl-search`:

```
ELISP> (setq test (list "apple" "pear" "grape"))
("apple" "pear" "grape")

ELISP> (cl-member "ap" test :test #'cl-search)
("apple" "pear" "grape")

ELISP> (cl-member "gra" test :test #'cl-search)
("grape")
```

Comment: Hopefully there are no regular expression metacharacters in your search string...

Answer (score 1):

A solution that almost doesn't require `cl-lib` (only `cl-defgeneric` and `cl-defmethod`):

```lisp
(seq-some (lambda (x) (string-match "foo" x)) '("f" "fo" "fooo"))
```

And a solution that doesn't require `cl-lib`

```lisp
(defun some-string-matches (search strings)
  (while (and strings (not (string-match search (car strings))))
    (setq strings (cdr strings)))
  strings)
```

Just so it would live up to the title.

Comment: This is elegant.

Comment: @npostavs it would be simply wrong if it were :) let me check. I thought it was Emacs' own.

Comment: @npostavs yeah, you are right. But let me search for a bit. I cannot believe Emacs Lisp doesn't have one of its own...

Comment: @npostavs but there's `seq-filter`! :P

Comment: Bummer, this one is also from CL-variety... hm.

Comment: "also from CL-variety" how do you mean? If you're talking about `cl-defgeneric`, that part is preloaded (at least in Emacs 25).

Comment: @npostavs It also uses `cl-map`, which is basically how `cl-some` is implemented. I think `cl-lib` is too tightly integrated into Emacs Lisp now that it would merit any effort put in avoiding it.

Comment: Ah, no, it uses `seq-map`. OK. So, it is a semi-non-cl solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Use mapcar, you can test anything in a lambda.

This example here will return multiple headings that start with "someday.org/Personal/Foo..." which is not what I want.

```lisp
;; Wrong dont use
(cl-member "someday.org/Personal" (org-refile-get-targets) :test 'string= :key 'car )
```

Instead use mapcar which only returns the correct one.

```lisp
;; Correct
(delq nil
(mapcar
  (lambda (x) (when (string= (car x) "someday.org/Personal") x)) (org-refile-get-targets)))
```